# LOAD DATA INFILE when fields real escaped fields contain \n and \"

Tags: mysql, libreoffice, into-outfile

Schema for my **sms** table is - sms(**id**, mobileNumber, text)

where text is of type *text*.

One of the row has below text -

```
Foo bar\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n\nconsectetur adipisicing elit, said:\n\n\" sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua don\'t \"
```

When I run this query -

```
select 'SMS ID', 'Mobile Number', 'SMS Text' 
union 
select id, ifnull(mobileNumber, 'Not Available'), text 
from sms
into outfile '/tmp/SMSUsage.csv' 
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

and open the CSV file in [Libreoffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice), I see the text in more than one cells like -

```
Foo bar\\\\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\\\n\\\\nconsectetur adipisicing elit, said:\n\n\
```

in one column and then each word after above sentence into a separate column.

Also Why does it put three extra '\' before '\n'? How do I get the text in a single cell?

Comment: Does it matter which program you use to open the file? Have you tried lines terminated by '\r\n'; ?

Comment: Yes. tried putting '\r\n'; That didn't work either. I think the problem is with `enclosed by` because when " occurs, it breaks the flow.

Comment: \n is escaped to \\n and it looks like its being escaped again to \\\\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'SMS ID', 'Mobile Number', 'SMS Text' 
UNION 
    SELECT id, IFNULL(mobileNumber, 'Not Available'), text 
    FROM sms
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/SMSUsage.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINTATED by ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```